# Fiware POI public servers

Tags: fiware, fiware-poi

Does any main public FIWARE POI server exist ?  Can I use in my application some public FIWARE POI server without creating my own one ?

Answer (score 2):

A public FIWARE POI **server** is at http://poi.lab.fiware.org/poi_dp . The data is public, but it is read-only for the public to keep the things simple. You can use a demo **browser** http://poi.lab.fiware.org/pois/ to view the POIs on the map. There is a POI **editor** http://poi.lab.fiware.org/pois/edit_poi.html for viewing detailed data, but the public cannot save the modifications.

*Status 2016-06-09: Populating with European POIs*

To store your own POIs it is recommended to set-up an own POI server. If you are in FIWARE, FICORE, etc. you might spawn a FIWARE POI instance at [FIWARE Lab](https://account.lab.fiware.org/). Otherwise you can use the Installation guide at [FIWARE POI GitHub page](http://chiru.github.io/FIWARE-POIDataProvider/). Installation to a Ubuntu 14.04 takes about half an hour by meticuously following the detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, review this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36064565/fiware-orion-subscription-with-georel-expression-in-condition

Comment: Sorry, not enough knowledge about fiware-orion.

Comment: Hello again.  Is a public demo read-only POI server, you've talked about, available now ? Is there any progress on the question?

Comment: Yes. We got the server up. You'll find it at http://poi.lab.fiware.org/poi_dp . We are loading something from OpenStreetMap. What is the main geographical area of your interest? The demo browser is at http://poi.lab.fiware.org/pois .

Comment: Thank you. The main geographical areas of our interest are Spain and France, for a start, and the whole world in prospect.