# Fiware orion subscription with georel expression in condition

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have an entity in my orion DB:

```
{
  "id"=>"User-121",
  "type"=>"User",
  "location"=>{
    "type"=>"geo:point", 
    "value"=>"59.851484, 30.199463"
  }, 
  "time"=>{"type"=>"none", "value"=>222909, "metadata"=>{}}
}
```

Also, I have 3 subscriptions to this entity, which have the same coordinates in condition's expression:

> 1. Should trigger when the entity is located, at least 100 meters far away from the reference point.

```
{
  "id"=>"...",
  "expires"=>"...",
  "status"=>"active",
  "subject"=>{
    "entities"=>[{"id"=>"User-121", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>"User"}],
    "condition"=>{
      "attributes"=>["location", "time"], 
      "expression"=>{
        "q"=>"", 
        "geometry"=>"point", 
        "coords"=>"59.851484, 30.199463", 
        "georel"=>"near;minDistance:100"}
    }
  },
  "notification"=>{
    "callback"=>"http://callback", 
    "attributes"=>["time"]
  }
}
```

> 2. Should trigger when the entity is located, at a maximum, 100 meters far away from the reference point

```
{
  "id"=>"...",
  "expires"=>"...",
  "status"=>"active",
  "subject"=>{
    "entities"=>[{"id"=>"User-121", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>"User"}],
    "condition"=>{
      "attributes"=>["location", "time"], 
      "expression"=>{
        "q"=>"", 
        "geometry"=>"point", 
        "coords"=>"59.851484, 30.199463", 
        "georel"=>"near;maxDistance:100"}
    }
  },
  "notification"=>{
    "callback"=>"http://callback",  
    "attributes"=>["time"]
  }
},
```

> 3. Should trigger when the entity is located at the reference point (has the same coordinates)

```
{
  "id"=>"...",
  "expires"=>"...",
  "status"=>"active",
  "subject"=>{
    "entities"=>[{"id"=>"User-121", "idPattern"=>"", "type"=>"User"}],
    "condition"=>{
      "attributes"=>["location", "time"], 
      "expression"=>{
        "q"=>"", 
        "geometry"=>"point", 
        "coords"=>"59.851484, 30.199463", 
        "georel"=>"equals"}
    }
  },
  "notification"=>{
    "callback"=>"http://callback", 
    "attributes"=>["time"]
  }
}
```

The problem is that all of the subscriptions send notifications each time  I update the entity. It doesn't even depend on the entity's coordinates values. Whatever the coordinates are, I always receive 3 notifications of any update.

What am I doing wrong ?

The Orion Context Broker version is **0.28.0** (git version: 5c1afdb3dd748580f10e1809f82462d83d2a17d4)

Comment: There is one more problem which, I think, is related to this one. When I try to search the entity right after creation, everything works fine. I use the same filter conditions as the ones that are present in the Subscriptions.  (e.g.: "geometry"=>"point", "coords"=>"59.851484, 30.199463", "georel"=>"near;minDistance:100" ).   But after I update the entity, the search stops working, even if the coordinates stays the same. I tried this on my own server and on the http://orion.lab.fiware.org service.

Comment: Could you edit your question post to include the Orion Context Broker version you are using, please? I mean, the one that is printed with `contextBroker --version`. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks for feedback !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geo-location features in NGSIv2 subscriptions have not been yet implemented (at Orion 0.28.0). Note that NGSIv2 is yet in beta status and sometimes [the specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/) (where the `geometry`, `georel` and `coords` are defined as part of `expression`) is a step forward the implementation.

There is [a github issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/1678) about this, to which you can subscribe in order to know when this feature gets implemented.

**EDIT**: geo-location features in NGSIv2 subscriptions will be available in Orion 1.3.0 (to be released by the end of August or begining of September). If you don't want to wait, note the functionality is also available in the develop branch (and associated Docker).

Comment: Please, review this too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37437225/fiware-orion-context-broker-subscriptions-condition-does-not-work

Comment: Edit answer to include an update on Orion functionality.